# Android Manifest not finding other XML resources

Tags: java, android, manifest

My Android Manifest is not finding any of the other resources.  I have not touched anything within the Manifest, with the exception of adding the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.malachowski.draw" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_nam" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

It can't find the ic_launcher, app_name, and AppName.  I have restarted Android Studio and cleaned the project. What would cause this issue?

Comment: I assume there's a closing `</manifest>` tag, right?

Comment: Also trying a Clean/Rebuild never hurt anyone...

Comment: It's not that you've touched anything in the manifest that causes your issue. A syntax error in another XML file (layouts etc) can cause this issue. The issue being your R file has not been generated (created) and therefore resources can't be found **legitimately**. One scenario is the R file is not generated when it is not possible due to some stray character in one of your XML files. What else did you change?

Comment: @Sam Yes, I'm not sure if it is not showing up for you but </manifest> is the last line in my code above.

Comment: @Blundell  I had a feeling it was something like that.  I will have to look through the XML files and see if anything looks off.

Comment: to add to what @Blundell said, sometimes I find it the quickest to look for the R.java file itself to see if it was generated at all, and look to see if there are any compilation errors in it (like a bad resource name or value). You can find this deep in the build folder, something like `build/generated/source/r/draw/debug/com/malachowski/draw/R.java` - then track down the problematic resource, clean/rebuild to regenerate `R.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was a bug in the version of Android Studio I was using. I updated it and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Creating project again in Android studio also worth, sometime project got corrupted while creating.

Sundeep Sharma